# Javascript getElementById when you dont know the ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am using PHP to assign a random ID to a checkbox, now I want to check that value of checkbox but because I don't know the ID, I dont know how to check it.

so here is the HTML :

```
<input class="citycheck" 
       id="<?php $city_id; // this is randomly generated ?>" 
       type="checkbox" 
       name="<?php echo $city_name"> <?php echo $city ?>

<div class"properties">Some Properties</div>
```

and my Javascript:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // right now I am checking by class
        // show or hide if it is already checked
        if ($(".citycheck").is(':checked'))
            $(".properties").show();
        else
            $(".properties").hide();

        // show or hide if user clicked on the checkbox
        $(".citycheck").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(".properties").show();
            } else {
                $(".properties").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

but because there are many checkbox with class `citycheck` when one is checked, if another city is not checked, the properties are still shown.

How can I check the value of checkbox by ID when I don't know the ID yet?

### Update

The reason I want the ID is because ID is unique and class is not. So using class, if one checkbox is checked it shows properties related to that class.

I have a checkbox for every city, every city had some properties, if I click on Chicago, then properties of Chicago are listed. Problem right now is that if I check Chicago, properties of Boston are also shown.

Comment: properties class have many or only one???

Comment: You want to use `getElementById()` but don't know id what does that mean?

Comment: @SudharsanS there are like 10 properties for each city

Comment: @Novice so I wanted to use `var id= document.getElementById('checkbox-ID');` and use it in the js but I dont know how to get the id

Comment: like `if ($(id).is(':checked'))`

Comment: Why would you need the ID? Anyway, inside click event, `this.id` would return the ID of clicked checkbox. Maybe what you want is something like: `$(".citycheck").filter(':checked').each(function(){console.log(this.id);})`. But you'd have better to explain what is your expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff because if one checkbox is checked, it shows all other properties for other items which are not checked.

Comment: But so you should ask question regarding how to show relevant `.property` depending checked checkbox, this has nothing to do with ID. You could use relevant jq transversal method depending index i guess. Ask new question instead

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes, but isnt basically check the ID of checkbox and show class property if it is checked?

Comment: Like i said, you can use `this.id` to check the ID of clicked checkbox, isn't it all your question? If you provide a simple example of what you are looking for, i guess someone could fix it in seconds. See [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How does knowing the ID of the checkbox solve the problem of knowing which properties to show? Do the properties have the checkbox ID in them somewhere?

Comment: @Barmar you are right, knowing the ID we can't hide or show the properties because they all have the same class. What a mess, do you have any proposed solution to this situation?

Comment: @user7309749 I guess: `$(".citycheck").change(function() { $(".properties").eq($(this).index('.citycheck')).toggle(this.checked); });`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a pseudo class in your element and use this pseudo class to find all the elements in your page. Then you can check which of them are checked and do whatever is needed. I did the same also for details by assigning a pseudo class. As it is now your html code if someone change the name of the class from citycheck to whatever the behavior of you UI will not change at all, provided that will note move the elements, since we rely on the `siblings`. Please have a look at the following snippet:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.js-citicheck').on("change", function(){
        var ele = $(this);
        var details = ele.siblings('div.js-details');
        if(ele.is(":checked")){
            details.show();   
        } else {
           details.hide();
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input class="citycheck js-citicheck" 
id="berlin" 
        type="checkbox" 
/>
<label for="berlin">Berlin</label>
<div class="details js-details" style="display:none">Berlin details.</div>
</div>
<div>
<input class="citycheck js-citicheck" 
id="london" 
        type="checkbox" 
/>
<label for="london">London</label>
<div class="details js-details" style="display:none">London details.</div>
</div>
<div>
<input class="citycheck js-citicheck" 
id="paris" 
        type="checkbox" 
/>
<label for="paris">Paris</label>
<div class="details js-details" style="display:none">Paris details.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: another class beside the citycheck class?

Comment: Yes, it is a common practice when you wan to you this class in js scripts, this class names has the prefix `js-`, in order to denote that this is used in or more js scripts.

Comment: the `$(".citycheck").click(function() {` will replace my `$(".citycheck").click(function() {`?

Answer (score 0):

You Can add a prefix to the id

```
<input class="citycheck" 
       id="<?php echo 'id_'.$city_id; ?>" // this is randomly generated 
       type="checkbox" 
       name="<?php echo $city_name"> <?php echo $city ?>

<div class"properties">Some Properties</div>
```

and then :

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="id_"]'); 

var list = $('[id^="id_"]');
```

traverse the list and check if it's checked or not

Comment: How does this solve the problem of showing/hiding the properties related to the checkbox instead of doing all the properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve everything you want to with simple jQuery selectors.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.properties').hide();
    $('.citycheck:checked + .properties').show();

    $('.citycheck').change(function(){
        $(this).next('.properties').toggle();
        alert('The id of this checkbox is: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });

});
```

```css
input {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="sdnflfldja" class="citycheck" type="checkbox" name="Alphaville">
<div class="properties">Some Properties</div>

<input id="sdnfldfj" class="citycheck" type="checkbox" name="Betaville">
<div class="properties">Some Properties</div>

<input id="szdnnadsc" class="citycheck" type="checkbox" name="Gammaville">
<div class="properties">Some Properties</div>

<input id="sallddfa" class="citycheck" type="checkbox" name="Deltaville">
<div class="properties">Some Properties</div>

<input id="adlkfkfddsl" class="citycheck" type="checkbox" name="Epsilonville">
<div class="properties">Some Properties</div>
```

Comment: Thank, I think this is a good approach, would this work if I change the html structure? like add properties in a list?

Comment: Yes, the approach above will work as long as the sibling element which  immediately follows `input.citycheck` has the class `.properties`. So if you wanted to add properties in a list you would follow your `<input>` with your `<ul class="properties">`.